# Have the number of Klingon Great Houses been established before Discovery?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In the opening scene of the pilot episode, the Klingon leader says that he plans to unite the 24 Great Houses. Later in her flashback, Michael’s Vulcan training includes a question of how many Klingon Great Houses there are and this is repeated.

Has this number been established in previous *Star Trek* media?

Comment: According to [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Great_House), there are only 12 known houses. Since ST:D is a prequel, maybe there really were 24 at the time and 12 were gone by ST:TNG's time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.**

Prior to Star Trek Discovery, no number is ever put on the Great Houses. As Remy Lebeau states in the comments, [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Great_House) has a list of Great Houses, but this is simply a compilation of all of the Great Houses mentioned on screen. At no time are the listed houses named together, nor are they ever described as a complete listing.